# How to transfer built in AccessToken Model to common folder in loopback

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I need to transfer AccessToken Model to common working directory in loopback,
I tried by simply copying the class , but it not working.
I had added some custome code in the function

```
AccessToken.findForRequest = function(req, options, cb) {
}
```

So that I cannot place this file in node_modules folder.
Please provide the steps to transfer this model class to common/model folder in the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a model inherited from `AccessToken`

or

in a boot script get `AccessToken` model and add your custom methods